# Check first word in file logic

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create a part in a program that opens a file, if the first word on the first row is "title" then I want it to write groups of input into the file, without the title row. If the file is empty and there is no first word "title" then I want it to write that row once, and then continue writing the other input boxes into the text file. I don't think i'm too far off, I just need another set of eye's on my logic.

Thank you!

My output is:

```
[Car]{bgcolor: ##fcecec}
*VIN{label: varchar, not null}
Make {label: varchar, not null}
Model {label: varchar, not null}
Year {label: varchar, not null}
Color {label: varchar, not null}
Miles {label: varchar, not null}

title {label: Database (condensed), size: 20}
[Owner]{bgcolor: ##ececfc}
*Fname{label: varchar, not null}
LName {label: varchar, not null}
Address {label: varchar, not null}
Phone {label: varchar, not null}
Employeer {label: varchar, not null}
Annual Income {label: varchar, not null}
Married {label: varchar, not null}
DOB {label: varchar, not null}

title {label: Database (condensed), size: 20}
[Employeer]{bgcolor: ##d0e0d0}
*Name{label: varchar, not null}
Address {label: varchar, not null}
Phone {label: varchar, not null}
Salary {label: varchar, not null}
Years with company {label: varchar, not null}
Job title {label: varchar, not null}
```

What it should look like is:

```
title {label: Database (condensed), size: 20}
[Car]{bgcolor: ##fcecec}
*VIN{label: varchar, not null}
Make {label: varchar, not null}
Model {label: varchar, not null}
Year {label: varchar, not null}
Color {label: varchar, not null}
Miles {label: varchar, not null}

[Owner]{bgcolor: ##ececfc}
*Fname{label: varchar, not null}
LName {label: varchar, not null}
Address {label: varchar, not null}
Phone {label: varchar, not null}
Employeer {label: varchar, not null}
Annual Income {label: varchar, not null}
Married {label: varchar, not null}
DOB {label: varchar, not null}

[Employeer]{bgcolor: ##d0e0d0}
*Name{label: varchar, not null}
Address {label: varchar, not null}
Phone {label: varchar, not null}
Salary {label: varchar, not null}
Years with company {label: varchar, not null}
Job title {label: varchar, not null}
```

My code is:

```
 'database name

    ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
    ' The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
    Using sr As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        Dim line, firstWord As String
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        ' Read and display lines from the file until the end of
        ' the file is reached.
        Do
            line = sr.ReadLine()

            If Not (line Is Nothing) And k = 0 Then
                firstWord = line.Split(" ")(k)
                If firstWord.Contains("title") Then
                    sr.Close() ' closes file
                    GoTo AttributeWrite
                Else
                    sr.Close() ' closes file
                    Dim TitleWrite As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True) ' open file
                    TitleWrite.WriteLine("title {label: " & TextBox10.Text & " (condensed)" & ", size: " & "20" & "}") ' write to file
                    TitleWrite.Close() ' closes file


                End If
            End If
        Loop Until k = 0
    End Using
```

Comment: What does the input file look like?  Don't use a GoTo statement.

Comment: The program as a whole generates the "input" file a sample of which is included above. When the program runs for the first time the file should be empty, however each iteration after that it should start with that line "title" and have each additional set of data added like the groups below

Comment: If your file is empty, your code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a text file,go with `File.ReadAllLines`.Create a list of string,then remove the string item at index (0). Sample :

```
 Dimm AllData as new List(Of String)

 For each Line in FIle.ReadAllLines(filepathhere)
 AllData.Add(Line)
 Next
 AllData.RemoveAt(0) 'This will remove the first line only
```

Or if `title` is not in the first line,then find the `index` of it and then remove it :

```
Dim index As Integer = AllData.FindIndex(Function(a) a = "title")
AllData.RemoveAt(Index)
```

Hope this helps :) .

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break and looking at it again I figured out where I had a problem.

I had to move the location of my one "end if"

Thank you to those who offered solutions :)

```
 If Not (line Is Nothing) And k = 0 Then
                firstWord = line.Split(" ")(k)
                If firstWord.Contains("title") Then
                    sr.Close() ' closes file
                    GoTo AttributeWrite
                End If  <----- THIS ONE

                Else
                    sr.Close() ' closes file
                    Dim TitleWrite As New 
  System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True) ' open file
                    TitleWrite.WriteLine("title {label: " & 
  TextBox10.Text & " (condensed)" & ", size: " & "20" & "}") ' write to file
                    TitleWrite.Close() ' closes file


                End If
```